# What is the verb for gardening?

Tags: verbs, word-requests

I came up with a bunch of nouns, so I'm thinking this is a suru verb.

Closest thing I came up with is 築庭する。 (chikutei suru), but it translates to landscape gardening.

Is there a more common usage?

Thank you! :)

I read somewhere in an example sentence that it could be niwashi suru, but when I looked up niwashi (gardener) it didn't have the noun listed as a suru verb so I am unsure :P !

Answer (score 11):

You can use ガーデニングする (do gardening) for gardening.

ガーデニング is a generally used term in today's Japan.

So you can say...

- 趣味の一つとして、ガーデニングを始めた。 (As one of my hobby, I started gardening.)
- ガーデニング用品を買う。 (Buy tools for gardening.)
- 子供と一緒にガーデニングした。(I gardened with my children.)

If you don't prefer this word, you can use [園芸]{えんげい}する (do gardening) alternatively.

ガーデニング sounds more modernized compared with 園芸.
If you do something in traditional Japanese-styled garden, you cannot use ガーデニング.

[造園]{ぞうえん} or [築庭]{ちくてい} sounds like creating large-scale garden from scratch.

[庭師]{にわし}する(Do gardener) is not a correct Japanese verb.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to knjname's answer, you can use `庭いじりする` for gardening. (Literally it means `to play with the garden`.)

`庭いじり` is a very common word for casual hobby gardening. ( http://matome.naver.jp/topic/1LwIE )

And also `庭仕事する` is common for gardening. (Literally it means `to work on the garden`, but  doesn't necessarily mean working as a job.)

`築庭する` sounds like very professional gardening.

And `庭師する` is wrong, as knjname says.